# How to load gridcombobox with dynamic datastore correctly?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I am working on a simple grid form which has a combobox and datasource as proxy (like http://goo.gl/2fxP8). The combobox loads properly but when I try to select one of the list items the gridform closes and combobox doesn't close. Can anyone help me out ?

I am planning to extend the combobox onselect function as well so that once the list item is chosen other fields will be loaded dynamically.

```
 searchField = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
     store: ds,
     name : 'search',
     id:'search',
     fieldLabel : 'Search',
     displayField:'title',
     typeAhead: false,
     loadingText: 'Searching...',
     pageSize:10, 
     minChars:2,
     triggerAction: 'all',
     width: 200,
     tpl: resTpl,
     itemSelector: 'div.search-item',
     onSelect: function(record){ 
     /* Set Values to other fields here */
     }
 }),
```

The code for saving is :

```
                                    Ext.Ajax.request
                                    ({  
                                    url:"some url",
                                    scope:this,
                                    params:
                                    {
                                    },
                                    success: function(objServerResponse)
                                    {
                                        eval("var resultSet = " +objServerResponse.responseText);
                                        if(resultSet.isOk)
                                        {

                                            this.collapse();
                                        }   
                                        else
                                        {


                                        }

                                    }
                                    });
```

Comment: After selecting an item you can hide the grid and combo by using its id.If you share how you are hiding the components then it is easy to find out where yo uare doing mistake.

Comment: The only place where i am calling on the hide function is on clicking a save button i have in the form During save if the form validates success then i call a .collapse.

Comment: please share that code then we can find the mistake.

Comment: Kiran, check the question again, i have added the save part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is you are OVERIDE the `onSelect` function..
take look [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/source/Combo.html) (try to find `onSelect`), `onSelect` method is private...
and as you can see, inside `onSelect` there is `collapse` function to call by default..
so, if you are overide `onSelect`.. your combo never collapse by default..
you have to do that manually.. like what kiran said...

and my question is, why did you overide the `onSelect` function ??..
if you need to do something When the combo was selected, why don't you set it as listeners ??

try change your code :

```
 onSelect: function(record){ 
 /* Set Values to other fields here */
 }
```

with this one :

```
listeners : {
   "select" : function(combo,data,idx){
        console.info(data);
   }
}
```

Comment: I was just trying out various methods, changing it to this code hasn't proven useful either as i have already done this.